# Setting iframe height to scrollHeight in ReactJS using IframeResizer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

The typical solution to the problem doesn't work in in React due to its dynamically generated component structure and event model, as opposed to traditional static HTML. I tried with react-iframe-resizer-super but not found perfect solution.

My code:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';

import ReactIframeResizer from 'react-iframe-resizer-super';


class Frame extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
    super();
}

componentDidUpdate() {

        const iframeResizerOptions = {
          // log: true,
          // autoResize: true,
          checkOrigin: false,
          // resizeFrom: 'parent',
          // heightCalculationMethod: 'max',
          // initCallback: () => { console.log('ready!'); },
          // resizedCallback: () => { console.log('resized!'); },
      };
    }


    render() {

        return (

            <div style={{position: 'relative'}}>
                <IframeResizer iframeResizerOptions={iframeResizerOptions}>
                    <iframe scrolling="no" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" allowfullscreen
                            style={{width:'100%', height:'100%'}}
                    }}></iframe>
                 </IframeResizer>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Then I got following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: IframeResizer is not defined
```

Is there a way in React to set the height of an iframe to the height of its scrollable contents or is there any alternative way to archive this requirement?

I refer following link:

[https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-iframe-resizer-supe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-iframe-resizer-super)r

Answer (score 2):

This question is long decease, but I thought I would add just in case anyone else looking for clarification on using react-iframe-resizer-super + iframe-resizer (JS)

The problem in the code above is a misspelling of the imported component.

`import ReactIframeResizer from 'react-iframe-resizer-super';`

Should be:

`import IframeResizer from 'react-iframe-resizer-super';`

As you've used it inside your `Frame` component.

For those looking for clarification on using the library, here is my dead simple working solution:

1. Install dependencies on React project containing iFrame `yarn add react-iframe-resizer-super iframe-resizer`
2. Include [iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js](https://raw.github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/master/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js) on the page that you are using as the source of your iFrame.
3. Usage in React:

**DynamicIFrame.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import IframeResizer from 'react-iframe-resizer-super';

export const DynamicIFrame = props => {
  const { src } = props;
  const iframeResizerOptions = {
    log: true,
    // autoResize: true,
    checkOrigin: false,
    // resizeFrom: 'parent',
    // heightCalculationMethod: 'max',
    // initCallback: () => { console.log('ready!'); },
    // resizedCallback: () => { console.log('resized!'); },
  };
  return (
    <IframeResizer src={src} iframeResizerOptions={iframeResizerOptions} />
  );
};
```